# How is AWS cloudformation internally build?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

How is AWS CloudFormation itself build. Is it based on a commercial or open source project or is it a complete home build solution? Is there any public documentation about it available from AWS?

Answer (score 1):

There is no detailed information about how most of the AWS services are working behind the curtain. AWS is usually builds it's services over its own API's of services, but this doesn't mean they are not using any 3rd party software. ( Like a library for parsing JSON or building a dependency tree, etc.)

If your question is because compliance issues, I would contact AWS technical support to get detailed information. ( I'm sure they can answer your question, since the AWS GovCloud should already asked all of these questions :D )

*And then summarise the answer here!*